# Get the value of a specific child from the result of a query in a Firebase database in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this sample database on Firebase:

Sample database

[image]

I have an index.html that have these two input text:

```html
...

<!--     LOGIN      -->
<div class="login-form" id="login">
  <h2>Login Form</h2>
  
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  
  <a class="btn-login" id="btn-login">Login</a>

...
```

I want to select a child that have the same "Username" of the inputText and then I want to verify if the password match.

I've tried with these query in the index.js file:

```js
var firebaseRootRef = firebase.database().ref();
var personale_Ref = firebaseRootRef.child('DatabaseTirocinio/Personale');

$(function() {
  $('#btn-login').click(function() {
    var id_user = $("#username").val();
    var id_password = $("#password").val();

    personale_Ref.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(id_user).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());

      var dip = personale_Ref.child(snapshot.key);

      dip.equalTo("Password").on("value", function(child) {
        console.log(child.val());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The first "console.log(snapshot.val())" show the right select of the child with the "Username" that I search for:

First consoleLog

[image]

But the second "console.log(child.val())" return "null".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the snap you are returning in the second query exists. It will tell you if the user with the password that has been entered exists in the database if not it will return null.

```
var firebaseRootRef = firebase.database().ref();
var personale_Ref = firebaseRootRef.child('DatabaseTirocinio/Personale');

$(function() {
  $('#btn-login').click(function() {
    var id_user = $("#username").val();
    var id_password = $("#password").val();

    personale_Ref.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(id_user).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());

      var dip = personale_Ref.child(snapshot.key);
        if(snapshot.exists()){
             Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(k => {
                if(k == "Password"){
                  console.log(snapshot.val()[k])
                }
             })
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: seems that it don't exist...
But the "Password" value exist in Firebase database.

Comment: pass custom password value without getting value from input type to check if data with that password and username is returned

Comment: do you mean in this way? :



    personale_Ref.orderByChild("Password").equalTo(12345).on("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());

Comment: yes here 12345 is the actual password saved for the user in your firebase. So if it is returning than check your input type password and print if it is same that you have saved in the firebase for that user or username password mismatch

Comment: The problem is that this query return the entire node that have a child with key/value Password/12345, that is the same result that you can see in "First consoleLog" that I attached.
But I need to get a specific child value of this result, in my case the "Password" value.

Comment: The process is first you will get a node on basis of exact username and then it will give you whole node so you can map through the keys using javascript to get only password key value from whole object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've find a solution (thanks to Himanshu), maybe not the best solution, so if anyone has any suggestion to improve it please leave a reply:

```js
var firebaseRootRef = firebase.database().ref();
var personale_Ref = firebaseRootRef.child('DatabaseTirocinio/Personale');

$(function() {
  $('#btn-login').click(function() {
    var id_user = $("#username").val();
    var id_password = $("#password").val();

    personale_Ref.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(id_user).on("value", function(snapshot) {

      var dipendente = snapshot.val();
      var dipKey = Object.keys(dipendente);
      var k = dipKey[0];

      if (dipendente[k].Password == id_password) {
        console.log("Ok");
      } else
        console.log("Wrong password");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly I have been telling that we can map through the keys in javascript using Object.keys().map()

Comment: Yes, I didn't know this method Object.keys(). Thank you very much.

Comment: If you find my answer useful please accept it. you can see my last comment on my answer telling map through object keys.

Comment: in your code 'k' is undefined... what does it represent?

Comment: It is by mistake I have edited my code,  it is the key for Object with help of which you can get its value

Comment: I copied and pasted your code.
It always prints the same thing as in the "First consoleLog" image that I have attached, also gives the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: child is not defined".
Instead my code gives the result I was looking for and does not give errors.
Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: you know its good main thing is that problem solved I have just given you a turn around how to deal with the situation you have. actually in place of child you have to use snapshot that you got after querying firebase.