# retrieve child value in firebase [web]

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve the child "hi" into a textbox, I have the code that retrieve the others, but I don't know how to retrieve a child of child, please help.

This is my database structure:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
mahasiswaRef = firebase.database().ref();
mahasiswaRef.on("value", function(snapshot)
{
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var files ="";
    for(var key in data)
    {
        files += "<tr>"+
                           "<td>" + data[key].nim+ "</td>"+ 
                           "<td>" + data[key].nama + "</td>"+
                           "<td>" + data[key].alamat + "</td>"+
                           "<td>" + data[key].usia + "</td>"+
                           '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-validasi="'+key+'">Edit</button>'+'</td>' +
                           '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-danger hapus" data-validasi="'+key+'">Hapus</button>'+'</td>' +
                          "<tr>";


    }

});
```

Comment: does this work `data[key].hello['hey']` ?

Comment: it does not work

Comment: then i would suggest you to console various attributes by `console.log(Object.keys(data[key]));` it'll help you see what are various attributes of the object. you might also see `hello` there maybe as an object, see how you can access it.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
mahasiswaRef = firebase.database().ref();
mahasiswaRef.on("value", function(snapshot){
var data = snapshot.val();          
var files ="";
    for(var key in data)
    {
        files += "<tr>"+
                           "<td>" +  data[key].nama .val()+ "</td>"+ 
                           "<td>" + data[key].alamat.val() + "</td>"+
                           "<td>" + data[key].usia.val() + "</td>"+
                           '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-validasi="'+key+'">Edit</button>'+'</td>' +
                           '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-danger hapus" data-validasi="'+key+'">Hapus</button>'+'</td>' +
                          "<tr>";


    }
      });
    });
```

Comment: My code works when retrieving these values, but I have a child of child cant retrieve it

Comment: Please visit this site: it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210281/get-the-value-of-a-specific-child-from-the-result-of-a-query-in-a-firebase-datab